# Uncommitted work pending from a non-DML access

Tags: apex, future, http

I'm trying to upload documents to a third party server. This is what I've come up with currently. I got several methods to preprocess the upload process and after that I run a loop to upload the files. However, when I try to run this I get the following error:

> System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please
>   commit or rollback before calling out Error is in expression
>   '{!upload}' in component  in page DocViewer:
>   Class.Uploader.logout: line 580, column 1 Class.Uploader.execute: line
>   47, column 1 Class.DocumentObjects.carryUpload: line 38, column 1
>
> Class.Uploader.logout: line 580, column 1 Class.Uploader.execute: line
>   47, column 1 Class.DocumentObjects.carryUpload: line 38, column 1

```
class Uploader
{
    public void execute()
    {
        try
        {
            login();
            ...
            preparation for upload
            ...
            upload(directory);

        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            String exceptionMessage = e.getMessage() + '\n' + e.getStackTraceString();
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, exceptionMessage));
            System.debug(exceptionMessage);
        }

        finally
        {
            logout();
        }
    }



    ....

    private void upload(String directoryName)
    {
        String uploadFolderPath = mainDir + '\\' + directoryName;
        String url = baseUrl + '/upload';
        for(Document obj : documentList)
        {
            String fileName = obj.Name + '.' + obj.Type;
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'Uploading ' + fileName));
            sendRequest(url, fileName, obj.BodyLength, obj.SystemModstamp, uploadFolderPath, obj.body, params.get('token'), params.get('syncWebFolderId'));
        }
    }

    @future (callout=true)
    private static void sendRequest(String url, String file_name, Integer fileSize, dateTime lastModified, String edgeFolderPath, Blob file_body, String token, String syncWebFolderId)
    {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();

        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data');
        req.setHeader('Token', token);
        req.setHeader('UploadPath', EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(syncWebFolderId + '\\' + edgeFolderPath)));
        req.setHeader('FileName', EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(file_name)));
        req.setHeader('FileSize', String.valueOf(fileSize));
        req.setHeader('FileModifiedtime', String.valueOf(lastModified.getTime()/1000));
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setBodyAsBlob(file_body);
        req.setTimeout(120000);

        res = http.send(req);
        Integer statusCode = res.getStatusCode();
        String statusMessage = res.getStatus();

        if(statusCode == 200)
        {
            DOM.Document doc = new DOM.Document();      
            doc.load(res.getBody());    
            DOM.XMLNode rootNode = doc.getRootElement();
            String errorCode = rootNode.getAttribute('errorCode', null);
            if(errorCode == '200')
            {
                if(ApexPages.currentPage() != null)  
                    ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'Upload done ' + file_name));
            }
            else
            {
                String errorMessage = rootNode.getAttribute('errorString', null);
                throw new CustomException('Error under upload. Error code: ' + errorCode + '. Error Message: ' + errorMessage);
            }
        }
        else
            throw new CustomException('Error under upload. Status code: ' + statusCode + '. Reason: ' + statusMessage);
    }

    private void logout(String token)
    {
        String url = baseUrl + '/Logout';
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setHeader('Token', token);
        res = http.send(req);

        Integer statusCode = res.getStatusCode();
        String statusMessage = res.getStatus();
        if(statusCode != 200)
        {
            String errorMessage = 'There was an error logging out. Status Code ' + statusCode + '. Reason: '+ statusMessage;
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, errorMessage));
            throw new CustomException(errorMessage);
        }
        ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM, 'Logged out!'));
    }

}
```

I intend to wait until the I get the response for all the uploads and then logout. Is there an executorService() like framework in Apex so that it can handle it? Or are there any future.isCompleted() like methods (Apache's HTTPRequest)? The test method mentioned contains Test.startTest() and Test.endTest() but I am still not sure how to incorporate this. I also need advice whether this has to be made a test class if I have to check the future's status. Can this be done in a non-test class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to work using [Batches](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) or more with the recent addition of [Queueable interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm). An example for Queueable interface:

```
 public with sharing class TestQueueable implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts{

    //Properties and constructor definition here
    ...
    ...

    public void execute(QueueableContext context)
    {
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http http = new Http();

        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data');
        req.setHeader('Token', token);
        req.setHeader('UploadPath', EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(syncWebFolderId + '\\' + edgeFolderPath)));
        req.setHeader('FileName', EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(file_name)));
        req.setHeader('FileSize', String.valueOf(fileSize));
        req.setHeader('FileModifiedtime', String.valueOf(lastModified.getTime()/1000));
        req.setEndpoint(url);
        req.setBodyAsBlob(file_body);
        req.setTimeout(120000);

        res = http.send(req);
        Integer statusCode = res.getStatusCode();
        String statusMessage = res.getStatus();

        if(statusCode == 200)
        {
            DOM.Document doc = new DOM.Document();      
            doc.load(res.getBody());    
            DOM.XMLNode rootNode = doc.getRootElement();
            String errorCode = rootNode.getAttribute('errorCode', null);
            if(errorCode == '200')
            {
                if(ApexPages.currentPage() != null)  
                    ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'Upload done ' + file_name));
            }
            else
            {
                String errorMessage = rootNode.getAttribute('errorString', null);
                throw new CustomException('Error under upload. Error code: ' + errorCode + '. Error Message: ' + errorMessage);
            }
        }
        else
            throw new CustomException('Error under upload. Status code: ' + statusCode + '. Reason: ' + statusMessage);
    }

}
```

And a few minor tweaks from the class Uploader:

```
private void upload(String directoryName)
    {
        String uploadFolderPath = mainDir + '\\' + directoryName;
        String url = baseUrl + '/upload';
        for(Document obj : documentList)
        {
            String fileName = obj.Name + '.' + obj.Type;
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'Uploading ' + fileName));
            //sendRequest(url, fileName, obj.BodyLength, obj.SystemModstamp, uploadFolderPath, obj.body, params.get('token'), params.get('syncWebFolderId'));

              jobList.add(System.enqueueJob(new TestQueueable(fileName, obj.BodyLength, obj.SystemModStamp, obj.body, edgeFolderPath, params.get('token'), params.get('syncWebFolderId'))));
        }
    }
```

Regularly check the status of the jobs for the response using [actionPoller](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionPoller.htm) until this is done.

Thanks everyone for the guidance.

Answer (score 3):

Spring '15 introduced a new feature: [Make Long-Running Callouts from a Visualforce Page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_continuation_overview.htm).

Here's the relevant code from the page:

```
public with sharing class ContinuationController {
    // Unique label corresponding to the continuation
    public String requestLabel;
    // Result of callout
    public String result {get;set;}
    // Endpoint of long-running service
    private static final String LONG_RUNNING_SERVICE_URL =
        '<Insert your service URL>';

   // Action method
    public Object startRequest() {
      // Create continuation with a timeout
      Continuation con = new Continuation(40);
      // Set callback method
      con.continuationMethod='processResponse';

      // Create callout request
      HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
      req.setMethod('GET');
      req.setEndpoint(LONG_RUNNING_SERVICE_URL);

      // Add callout request to continuation
      this.requestLabel = con.addHttpRequest(req);

      // Return the continuation
      return con; 
    }

    // Callback method
    public Object processResponse() {  
      // Get the response by using the unique label
      HttpResponse response = Continuation.getResponse(this.requestLabel);
      // Set the result variable that is displayed on the Visualforce page
      this.result = response.getBody();

      // Return null to re-render the original Visualforce page
      return null;
    }
}
```

You call it like any normal action function:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!startRequest}" value="Start Request" reRender="result"/>
```

This also lets you work around the DML error, and even lets you chain requests together.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. How do you deal with multiple request and responses? My idea is to have a List<String> responseList; Map<String, Continuation> conMap to keep track of continuation. I hit a dead end when returning the values. Can you give me details on this scenario?

Comment: @dmachop Let me build a mockup. It shouldn't be too hard, I'd think.

Comment: [This](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_continuation_multiple_callouts.htm) gives out an example using multiple callouts. The problem with this approach is that you will not be able to perform more than 3 callouts. I have got about 30 selected objects but I guess this will not suit the scenario.